# How to extract error message from transaction using ethers.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, solidity, ethers.js

I use custom error in my Solidity contract:

`error Documents__AlreadyExist(string hash);`

This is my modifier:

```
modifier alreadyExist(string memory hash) {
      if (s_documentsHashes[hash]) {
         revert Documents__AlreadyExist(hash);
      }

      _;
}
```

And start of my solidity function:
`function addDocumentHash(string memory hash) external alreadyExist(hash) {}`

I use ethers.js (version 5.7) to call this contract function:

```
try {
    const tx = await documents.addDocumentHash(hash)
    const txReceipt = await tx.wait(1)
         
    // rest of the code
} catch (error) {   
    context.error(error)
}
```

If I run above code with hash that already exist I get this error:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9c3I.png)

My question is: How can I extract my custom error (Documents__AlreadyExist) from error that I get above?

Maybe I am doing somethin wrong because on Etherscan I cannot see the reason why my transaction failed (only that it was reverted)...

I tried to change ethers providers (Alchemy, Infura, Etherscan) but error is the same every time and I do not see the way to extract my custom error message from error that I get.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a much easier way to extract the name of the custom error in your smart contract with the ethers lib.

First, install [ethers-decode-error](https://github.com/superical/ethers-decode-error) and `ethers` in your project:

```
npm install ethers-decode-error ethers --save
```

You can skip installing `ethers` if you already have it in your project.

Next, the following code will help you to get the message of the custom error in your solidity contract:

```js
import { ErrorDecoder } from 'ethers-decode-error'
import type { DecodedError } from 'ethers-decode-error'

// Based on the snippet in your question, I presume you already have `documents` as an instance of your contract.

const errorDecoder = ErrorDecoder.create([document.interface])

try {
  const tx = await documents.addDocumentHash(hash)
  const txReceipt = await tx.wait(1)
} catch (err) {
  const { name } = await errorDecoder.decode(err)

  // Prints "Documents__AlreadyExist"
  console.log('Custom error name:', name)
}
```

I notice that your custom error `Documents__AlreadyExist` also has parameters to it. If you need to get the value of those parameters from your custom error, here's an example:

```js
try {
  const tx = await documents.addDocumentHash(hash)
  const txReceipt = await tx.wait(1)
} catch (err) {
  const decodedError = await errorDecoder.decode(err)
  const reason = customReasonMapper(decodedError)

  // Prints "Document of hash 0xInputHash already exist"
  console.log('Custom error message:', reason)
}

const customReasonMapper = ({ name, args, reason }: DecodedError): string => {
  switch (name) {
    case 'Documents__AlreadyExist':
      return `Document of hash ${args[0]} already exist.`

    // You can match other custom errors you may have in your contract here...

    default:
      return reason ?? 'There was an error'
  }
}
```

You can find more examples for handling solidity custom errors [here](https://github.com/superical/ethers-decode-error?tab=readme-ov-file#custom-errors).

Answer (score 0):

If hash is bytes32, it is better to use bytes32 instead of string to save gas.

https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xa13244879b3d475b66288af221383cce53c788827d0c96f449aecbece43ff3b4

```
  try {
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(
      "0xe6bD6b317E0136Df4E6bBb6329507D3537FbD1Da",
      abi,
      provider
    );

    // const owner = await contract.callStatic.getOwner();
    // console.log(owner);
    const re = await contract.callStatic.addDocumentHash(
      "570246ea5faa35cfafab75257ce2cc8e9c07d24e6185528ee63a050ea542b141"
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

I use ethersjs call your contract, catch (error) and get error.

`(method="addDocumentHash(string)", data="0x8f1e19540000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004035373032343665613566616133356366616661623735323537636532636338653963303764323465363138353532386565363361303530656135343262313431", errorArgs=["570246ea5faa35cfafab75257ce2cc8e9c07d24e6185528ee63a050ea542b141"], errorName="Documents__AlreadyExist", errorSignature="Documents__AlreadyExist(string)", reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)`

decode error data

```
    const errordata =
      "0x8f1e19540000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004035373032343665613566616133356366616661623735323537636532636338653963303764323465363138353532386565363361303530656135343262313431";
    const iface = contract.interface;
    const selecter = errordata.slice(0, 10);
    const res = iface.decodeErrorResult(selecter, errordata);
    const errorName = iface.getError(selecter).name;
    console.log(errorName);
    console.log(res.toString());
```

Comment: Ok, but I actually want to change my Smart Contract state so I can't use callStatic property, right? And if I do something like this: const re = await contract.addDocumentHash(''); await re.wait(); Then I get this error [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9c3I.png) and I see no way to extract error message from this error. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to analyze the thrown error, there must be data about the error. You can try `console.log(error.error.error.error.data);`

Comment: As I said, there is no error property in the error object

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to parse the error message in ethers 5

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers';

export function decodeContractError(contract: ethers.Contract, errorData: string) {
    const contractInterface = contract.interface;
    const selecter = errorData.slice(0, 10);
    const errorFragment = contractInterface.getError(selecter);
    const res = contractInterface.decodeErrorResult(errorFragment, errorData);
    const errorInputs = errorFragment.inputs;

    let message;
    if(errorInputs.length > 0) {
        message = errorInputs.map((input, index) => {
            return `${input.name}: ${res[index].toString()}`;
        }).join(', ');
    }

    throw new Error(`${errorFragment.name} | ${message ? message : ""}`);
}
```

You can use the above helper function to decode error

> Note: Ethers will have error data in `error.error?.data?.data` or
> `error.error?.error?.error?.data`

```
//Handle error
  private handleError(contract: ethers.Contract, error: any) {
    if (error.error?.data?.data) {
      decodeContractError(contract, error.error.data.data);
    } else if(error.error?.error?.error?.data) {
      decodeContractError(contract, error.error.error.error.data);
    } else { 
      throw error
    }
  }


//Pass the contract instance and error message
erc20.transfer("some_address", 10e18).catch(e => handleError(erc20, e));
```

Thrown Error

```
Error: ERC20InsufficientAllowance | spender: some_address, allowance: 0, needed: 100000000000000000000
```